# Коти мурчать, муркочуть чи муркотять?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, морфологія

Знайшла різне формулювання. Наприклад, на сайті [Gazeta.ua](http://meetgray.com/ukr/pochemu-koty-murchat.html) є стаття "Чому коти **мурчать**?". Там же натрапила і на таке речення:

> "Якщо спостерігати за кішкою на протязі довгого часу, ви можете помітити, що кішки **муркотять** не тільки тоді, коли їм добре, але і при стресі, або від болю."

На іншому сайті [A-YAK.COM](http://a-yak.com/chomu-kishki-murkochut/) подається стаття, в якій використовується третя форма слова: "Чому кішки **муркочуть**".

То яка ж форма правильна?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Академічний тлумачний словник (1970—1980)](http://sum.in.ua/s/murkotaty)

> **МУРКОТАТИ**, **очу**, **очеш** і **МУРКОТІТИ**, **очу**, **отиш**, *недок*.
>
> 1. *неперех*. Безперестанно видавати звуки «мур-мур» (про котів та інших котячих). *[Варка:] Як почне було Зінько читать, то я слухаю-слухаю, а далі й задрімаю, і почне мені вчуватись, що нібито котик муркоче під самісіньким вухом* (Марко Кропивницький, II, 1958, 226); *На лаві солодко муркотів кіт* (Василь Кучер, Трудна любов, 1960, 437);  * Образно. *Заспокоєне після цілоденної колотнечі місто стиха муркоче, мов левиця коло своїх малят у барлозі* (Петро Колесник, Терен.., 1959, 246).
> 2. *перех*. і без додатка, *перен*., *розм*. Те саме, що [мурмотати 1](http://sum.in.ua/s/murmotaty). *— Ну, що, сину? — спитав батько. Густав не відповідав, муркотячи під носом цифри, котрі то додавав, то відтягав* (Іван Франко, III, 1950, 76); *Господи! краще з тобою В темних сидіти шинках, Ніж муркотіти без тебе Всі молитви в вівтарях* (Агатангел Кримський, Вибр., 1965, 229); *Старий іде, посмоктуючи цигарку, муркочучи дідівську пісню* (Юрій Яновський, IV, 1959, 259).
>
> **МУРЧА́ТИ**, **чу**, **чиш**, *недок*.
>
> 1. *неперех*. Те саме, що **муркотати 1**. *Слухаю я — і борсук у норі мурчить* (Словник Грінченка); *Мурчав ситий кіт, жмурив проти сонця зелені очі* (Анатолій Шиян, Переможці, 1950, 39).
> 2. *перех*. і без додатка, *перен*., *розм*. Те саме, що [мурмотати 1](http://sum.in.ua/s/murmotaty). *У вікно загляне [Мафтей], чомусь у печі довбає довго і все мурчить щось про себе* (Гнат Хоткевич, II, 1966, 93); *— Говори, Тучинський, не мурчи. Нічого поглядати на мене* (Олесь Досвітній, Вибр., 1959, 189); *— Іди, іди, поки не дав, — сказав той, скручуючи цигарку.. — Не мурчіть, я маю діло* (Іван Микитенко, II, 1957, 253).

[Визначення дієвідміни](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/morfologija_i_pravopis/viznachennja_dievidmini_dieslova/6-1-0-126)

- **Муркотати** 3 ос. мнж. [мурко́чуть](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8), бо основа інфінітива **а**.
- **Муркотіти** 3 ос. мнж. [муркотя́ть](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8), бо основа інфінітива **і**.
- **Мурчати** 3 ос. мнж. [мурча́ть](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%80%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8), бо основа інфінітива **а**.

Отже,  ці 3 слова можна вживати.